# Jenkins can't update Subversion plugin

Tags: svn, plugins, jenkins

I need to update my Subversion PlugIn in Jenkins for my current work but every time I try to update the ***CVS*** and ***Subversion PlugIn*** I receive a fail notification stating "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I have closed TortoiseSVN status cache seeing that it has caused similar issues with other builds.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor274.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:239)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:307)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:298)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:298)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:298)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:422)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:129)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:413)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried restarting the server but it does not seem to make a difference. Any advice on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here shows you that some other process has a lock on the file antlr-runtime-3.4.jar.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

You would need to find out which process has a lock on that file, kill it or use the "Unlocker" tool to remove the lock if it's not a critical process.

Comment: Great thanks with help from [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) found the problem real quick.